# Parallel.For VS for - How to lock the variable?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Hello I have a sample of code but I'm not sure how to lock the variables in Parallel.For, my understanding is that many threads at the same are using the variables used inside the for.

```
int VVA=0;

for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
        {
            if (result[i] == 'a')
                va++;                
        };
```

//Result with normal for: 5000

```
Parallel.For(0, result.Count, index => 
        {
            if (result[index] == 'a')
                va++;
            
            Interlocked.Add(ref VVA, va); 
        });
```

//Result with parallel for: 43565646 (something like that)

What is missing here? thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `va` initialized as? What is being printed? What is the value of `result.Count`?

Comment: `Interlocked.Add` is thread-safe, but your `va++` is not, because `va` is declared outside of the loop body. So you're adding `va` to `VVA`, but you've mutated `va` in a non thread-safe way, so it's not clear what its value will be at a given point.

Comment: Hi...

result is a list... and count can be whatever, for example 50000 elements.
Va starts with 0 @PatrickRoberts

Comment: @John I want the same resutl as the normal for in the parallel for.

how can be that possible?

Comment: @Vmax Use the thread-safe `Increment` method instead of `va++;`. Note that your second method is just logically incorrect anyway, and you'd get the wrong result even without involving multi-threading.

Comment: It's correct it should be:

otherVar = Interlocked.Increment(ref va);

and otherVar  will have the right amount. @John thanks a lot!